# PHP architecture - Individual cron job per user

Tags: php, api, cron, architecture, ip

I'm building a website in PHP and need an API to be checked on a regular basis for EACH USER individually.

In a nutshell it's a SaaS to steer a user account on another website with additional/automated options. A web based bot if you want.

So basically, I need to dynamically create a new cron job with its individual interval for each user, and these should be executed in parallel (it would take too long to put all queries into one cron job if theres a lot of users).

Also, it might become necessary that each request is done with a different IP. Reason is that it is possible that the API provider is annoyed by us and wants to block us. Since the API key is public they will most likely do it by simply blocking our IP. When we change that frequently, that should help a lot.

Is something like that possible? What would this require? Any option that doesn't get too expensive?

I thought of RabbitMQ for example, but that wouldn't quite tackle all issues and I'm wondering if there's some better/smarter solution.

Thanks!

Comment: You can not just “fake” the requesting IP. You’d need to move this to a different server, or get a different IP assigned to your existing server every time. Both not very practical.

Comment: _“it would take too long to put all queries into one cron job if theres a lot of users”_ - a), the usual PHP execution time limits can be suspended for CLI. b) The cron itself does not have to do _all_ of it every time it runs, you can implement a system that uses the cron only to trigger a script that will check a queue of tasks to be performed, and then picks the next one. A separate cron for every app user is a bad idea.

Comment: Ah, so you're saying one cron job that runs basically every second to check if a task "is up". Still, there might be so many users that the queries take too long so they'd have to be executed in parallel (a simple time limit wouldn't solve the issue). That could indeed be done with message queueing, ok.
As for the IP - maybe the individual message queue workers can be on different machines with different IPs? Or maybe it's possible to use a Proxy for the requests?
Not sure what approach is best practice here, but there has to be something since this is a not a new thing :)

Comment: The minimum interval for cron is 1 minute with any standard implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at [temporal.io](https://temporal.io/) open source project. It supports practically an unlimited number of such periodic jobs. The PHP SDK can be found [here](https://github.com/temporalio/sdk-php).